# Responsive Tabs - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to edit the information displayed in the "property-page-template" of my theme, however am unsure of where to edit it.

The "features" of the page are coming from the below code but I cannot find 'features' in any other template files in order to edit it?

This is the php section of my "property-page-template" which seems to call the 'features' displayed:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); if(trim(get_field('features'))!=''){ ?>
                <div id="features"><?=html_entity_decode(get_field('features'))?></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#responsiveTabsDemo').responsiveTabs({
        startCollapsed: 'accordion'
    });
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".gallery-img .gallery").fancybox({
           'titlePosition'  : 'over'
        });
    });
</script>
```

The content I would like to edit is on this page in the "features" tab at the bottom
[Link to website](https://i-b-a.co.za/37-la-mer/)

Answer (score 0):

Or you edit the code like:

```
 <div id="features">MYINFORMATION</div>
```

Or can you define a new variable like:

```
function myInfo() {

echo "MYINFORMATION";
}
```

Or i think you can find get_field('features') in the DB